# Usage of 'and' as a noun

Tags: nouns, conjunctions

I am reading *The day that changed the world* by Stephen King and in the beginning he mentions that there is a correct usage of *and* as a noun. Unfortunately, he only mentions it.

I Googled for a long time but phrases with such common words as *noun* or *and* gave me various amounts of unnecessary web sites.

Can *and* be used as a noun? If so, in what way?

Comment: Any word in your question can be used as a noun. The and, the of, the a, the that — really any word.

Comment: If ifs and ands were pots and pans there'd be no need for tinkers. That shows it clearly - no ifs, ands or buts.

Comment: Of course, that's mention, not usage. Strictly speaking, it doesn't count. There's a logical usage of AND as a verb, but even in logic any noun AND is mention, not usage, because it's a functor, not an argument.

Comment: The answer/ clarification is in John Lawler's comment.

Comment: By the way, searching Google with the term *and* is pointless. You did the right thing by asking on ELU. Check out ELL: ell.stackexchange.com -- the right place to ask these Qs. HTH

Comment: @JohnLawler  John, a sincere question: In the sentence, "And is a conjunction," what part of speech is _And_? (I am leaving out the quotation marks I would normally place around _And_, because if it's valid to do so, it seems to focus the question even more.)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg: Any word may be mentioned, i.e, quoted, which makes it (usually) a noun that is the name of the word, as in the sentence you cite. Parts of Speech refer to **use**, not mention. This is an old problem in philosophy, endlessly recirculated and relearnt; see [_Use/Mention Distinction_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction). And putting quote marks around (or italicizing) words is one way to maintain it in print.

Comment: @JohnLawler: To clarify re use vs mention - you are referring to RegDwight's comment. I believe StoneyB covered use. Do you agree?

Comment: Reg's comment was about mention. Stoney's was mixed, with canonical uses followed by mentions (_If ifs and ans_). I just commented on the distinction, and let others interpret it as they please, like they did.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I'd agree with John Lawler, but his comment does raise one other possibility - use of AND in computer logic.   Processor instruction sets (like x86) include binary operations, such as AND.   In most contexts where you'd refer to one, it could probably be called an "AND gate" or an "AND operation", but I've heard people refer to just "AND" or "ANDs" as nouns.   (And yes, binary operations are usually all-caps.)   Kind of a stretch, but it's something.   I would guess King was either referring to what JL calls "mention", or just being enigmatic.

Comment: Ahem.   I could swear I saw a guideline saying that you should comment when voting down, so the 'downvotee' knows what the problem was.